# Does anyone know if VS-Code Cache's data anywhere other than `~/.cache`?

Tags: directory, cache

Everywhere I look on google, I find out how to clear the VS-Code cache data on windows. To be fair, even though it is an open source project, its being built from Microsoft's dollar, and by MS developers.

Anyhow, I use Ubuntu (obviously), always have, and always will #Linux4Life. I would like to clear all of .VSCode's cached data, however, like much of the other Microsoft built software out there, Microsoft puts things in, what I consider to be, weird places.

[I found one thread/question, on StackOverflow.com (this text is the link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234428/how-do-you-clear-your-visual-studio-code-cache-on-a-mac-linux-machine). The author suggested the following:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Cache/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/CachedData/*
```

I haven't tried typing it into the command-line, but I'm certain by looking at it that it is not going to do anything on my machine, as those (dir/file)-paths don't reference anything on my machine, or on any Ubuntu Distro that I know of. The question was in reference to Mac/Linux, so I am guessing the above is a Unix/Mac thing. despite one example displaying Forward slashes, and the other displaying backslashes. I would love if somebody knew something.

Comment: Check something like `~/.vscode*` .

Comment: @N0rbert **`/.vscode`** only contains the extensions directory, which holds the extensions obviously, but no cache. I opened **`~/.cache/Code`** — poked around a bit, and only found cached data for the debugger, so... IDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is located in the directory of the user that installed it: `/home/user/.config/Code`.

Inside there are three directories: `Cache`, `CachedData`, and `CachedExtensionVSIXs`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the answer Jony.

Comment: Can these 3 directories be safely deleted?

Answer (score 0):

from [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_hot-exit):

> ### Hot Exit
>
> [...] all backups are stored in the following folders for standard install locations:
>
> - Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\Backups`
> - macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups`
> - Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/Backups`